# The difference between x and z

Tags: verilog

While reading the syntax of Verilog, I came across the four logic values: `0 1 x z`.
After searching the web, seeking to find the difference between `x` and `z`, I found only that `x` is unknown value and `z` is high impedance (tristate). I think that I understand the definition of `x` but didn't quite understood the one of `z` - what does it mean "high impedance (tristate)"?

I would like to see an example for each logic value out of the two: `x z`

Answer (score 15):

Z means the signal is in a high-impedance state also called tri-state. Another signal connected to it can change the value: a 0 will pull it low, a 1 will pull it high.

To understand impedance (and thus high impedance) you should have some understanding of resistance, voltage and current and their relations as defined by Ohms law.

I can't give you an example of 'X' or 'Z',  just as I can't give you an example of '1' or '0'. These are just definitions of signal states. In fact in Verilog there are more then four states. There are seven strengths.
(See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20201022054201/https://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00047.htm) webpage).

Here is a principle diagram of how a chip output port makes a zero, one or Z. In reality the switches are MOSFETs.

[image]

Tri-state signals are no longer used inside chips or inside FPGA's. They are only used outside for connecting signals together.

Comment: your last comment about tri-state not being used "on chips" seems a bit off... for example what if you have an SoC with package-on-package, or a multi-chip module where you've got a CPU and some DDR RAM? Even in a non-SoC regime, the memory controller in the CPU will still need to internally support tri-state to conform with the JEDEC spec.

Comment: That is a matter of nomenclature. I would not call two die in a package like in a POP a 'chip'. In fact the term "multi-chip module" says it all: it is multiple chips.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is old. A huge number of CPUs out there have multiple cores on the same die. I worked on a CPU where we had dozens (over a hundred) of cores all connected together on a bus/ring...again, all on the same die (or chip or whatever you want to call it...it was the same silicon). The bus connections used Tri-state. I suspect my chip wasn't unique with this, and tri-state is a lot more common than you think.

Comment: @oldfart what about floating gate flash, or charge-trap flash. Aren't those tri-state sort of situations?

Answer (score 4):

`x`, as you had already found describes an `unknown` state. By default verilog simulation starts with all variables initialized to this value. One of the task of the designer is to provide correct reset sequences to bring the model into a `known` state, without 'x', i.e.

```
 always @(posedge clk)
    if (rst)
        q <= 0;
```

In the above example initial value of `q` which was `x` is replaced by a known value of `0`.

The difference between 'x' and 'z' is that 'z' is a `known` state of high impedance, meaning actually `disconnected`. As such, it could be driven to any other value with some other driver. It is used to express tri-state buses or some other logic.

```
 wire bus;
 assign bus = en1 ? value1 : 1'bz;
 ...
 assign bus = en2 ? value2 : 1'bz;
```

In the above example the `bus` is driven by 2 different drivers. If 'en1' or 'en2' is high, the bus is driven with a real 'value1' or 'value2'. Otherwise its state is 'z'.

verilog has truth tables for every operator for all the values. You can check how they are used. i.e. for '&'

```
&  0 1 x z

0  0 0 0 0
1  0 1 x x
x  0 x x x
z  0 x x x
```

you can find for every other gate as well. Note that there are no 'z' in the result, just 'x's.

Comment: thanks, needed to figure out how to store `0xZ` and `0xX` to numeric/digital data types!

Answer (score 2):

In system verilog X is treated like unconnected wire and Z is Weak HIGH.

Suppose a situation where you have wire connecting 2 modules m1 and m2.
If you are driving Z onto that wire from m1 then you can pull down this wire by assigning it to zero by m2.

Answer (score 0):

As I figured out :
"tristate" or "high impedance" In transistors occures when you have "**nothing**" in the output.
that may occur, for example :
In a situation that you have an nMOS transistor let's call that T1:

- the gate value of T1 is for example 0
  so T1 would not conduct and there is no conduction path between your supply (probably 0 ) and the drain(output)
  -that may occur a "Z" or tristate
  --
  It may occur for PMOS transistors with value -> 1 too.